# Open sets in Lindelöf space are Lindelöf?

Tags: general-topology

> Are Open sets in  Lindelöf space are Lindelöf?

So I saw some other posts about this and the answer was no.

But I can't understand what's the problem with the following-

If it was about closed sets:

Let $A$ be a closed set,$C$ an open cover of $A$. So $A^C$ is open,and $C\cup A^C$ is an open cover of $X$ (The Lindelöf space).Therefore,there is a countable subcover $C'$,and we can deduce from it a countable subcover of $C$ for $A$.

So why can't we do(almost) the same if $A$ is open?

Simply take $A$,and open cover of $A$,$C$,and another open cover for $A^C$, $C_2$,and continue in a similar way, where $C\cup C_2$ cover $X$?

Comment: Explain how this "(almost) the same" for open sets would look like.

Comment: @Wojowu As I said in the folllowing sentence...

Comment: Look at the example $X = [0, \omega_1]$ which is compact, $A = [0, \omega_1)$, $C = \{ [\alpha, \alpha + \omega) : \alpha < \omega_1 \}$.  Then the point is the countable subcover you get from your argument will necessarily account for some of the points in $A$ which are not in any element you chose from $C$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/494918/28900).

Comment: Because if $A$ is not closed and $D$ is a countable subset of $C\cup C_2$ that covers $X$  then $D$ might necessarily contain members of $C_2$ that have non-empty intersection with $A,$ so $D\cap C$ might fail to cover $A.$

Answer (score 3):

There may not be an open cover of $A^c$ consisting of sets disjoint from $A$.

Consider the set $X:=[0,1)$ with
$$
   \tau := \{U \subseteq X \mid 0\not\in U\} \cup\{X\}.
$$
This defines a topology on $X$ that makes $X$ into a Lindelöf (actually compact) space. However the open subset $(0,1)$ in $X$ is uncountable and discrete, and thus not Lindelöf.

Comment: I understand your example,but what's the problem with an open cover of $A^c$ that intersects $A$?

Comment: @ChikChak Because then part of your countable subcover may not come from the original cover you had of $A$.

Comment: AH I see,thanks!